# Cannot copy paste collections anymore

Tags: blend-files, collections, versions, layers, outliner

I ran into a problem when installing the new blender 2.83.
When copying a collection and pasting it, either in the same file or in another file, it doesn't work anymore. I get the notification that the data blocks have been pasted, but I see nothing in the collection outliner. (they appear in the blender file layer in the outliner, but they are not working)

I can append collections, but it takes too much time compared to copy paste in v 2.80. I can also Select all the files separately and copy paste them, but then all my work of organizing them into collections is basically gone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it changed, but it only adds one more step.
Open another Outliner set to Blender File and drag-n-drop collections into any scene.

*Example: Copy-pasting 'Monkey Collection' from another file.*
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helps me already a lot!